# Re-use memory from String to byte array conversion with ArrayPool in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection

Is it possible to re-use memory that was used in a string to byte array conversion?

The application has to send large strings over network with 60fps. This seems to put way too much pressure on the GC. So is it possible to re-use the byte arrays created by the string conversion somehow?

These are my current serialization methods:

```
public static byte[] SerializeJson(DrawDescriptionLayer layer)
{
    var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(layer, js);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s); //rent from array pool here
}
```

Or using streams:

```
public static byte[] SerializeJson2(DrawDescriptionLayer layer)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
    using (JsonTextWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
    {
        JsonSerializer ser = JsonSerializer.Create(js);
        ser.Serialize(jsonWriter, layer);
        jsonWriter.Flush();
        return ms.ToArray(); //rent from array pool here
    }
}
```

I am aware that i should write a custom binary serializer, but Newtonsoft.Json worked out of the box and the app uses third party types that have no serialization attributes.

Comment: Haven't used it at production level although there are some definite use cases that I can think off. You may get a bit more ideas from here (https://adamsitnik.com/Array-Pool/)

Comment: You might see some improvement using `MemoryStream.GetBuffer()` instead of `MemoryStream.ToArray()` - the former returns the stream's internal buffer rather than copying to a new byte array. The caveat is that the internal buffer will likely be larger than the stream length, so you'll need to pass the stream length around as well (or perhaps use `ArraySegment<byte>`).

Comment: @Iridium good hint, i could copy the buffer into a pooled array since the count of the stream is known. that might save one array garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

As far as streams, [Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream](https://github.com/Microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream) was specifically created to reduce the cost of garbage collections incurred by frequent large allocations. You could modify your stream example like:

```
private static readonly RecyclableMemoryStreamManager _manager = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();

public static byte[] SerializeJson2(DrawDescriptionLayer layer)
{
    using (var ms = _manager.GetStream())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
    using (JsonTextWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
    {
        JsonSerializer ser = JsonSerializer.Create(js);
        ser.Serialize(jsonWriter, layer);
        jsonWriter.Flush();
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The use of ToArray(), however, copies into a new array that is never pooled, which according to the docs "... wipes out many of the benefits of RecyclableMemoryStream completely.". So look into using GetBuffer() instead.

Answer (score 1):

If performance and memory allocation are major concerns, you should strongly consider using [utf8json](https://github.com/neuecc/Utf8Json).

Instead of using both the slow `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method, followed by the allocation-heavy `UTF8.GetBytes`, utf8json can do this in one pass:

```cs
public byte[] SerializeJson(DrawDescriptionLayer layer)
{
    return Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(layer, Utf8Json.Resolvers.StandardResolver.Default);
}
```

The library is optimized towards performance and low allocation, and it's used in software like ElasticSearch's recommended .NET client.

Also make sure that the `DrawDescriptionLayer` is a DTO that is highly optimized for cheap JSON serialization and doesn't contain anything not used in the network transfer.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for bringing the Utf8Json serializer up, it looks quite good but it's not able to serialize my object tree, it's probably not as mature as Newtonsoft.Json, which works in my case.

Comment: You're welcome! Can't help thinking that using a DTO to simplify the complex object tree could save a lot in both CPU, GC and network bandwidth, so it's highly recommended to consider. But it would be super helpful if you could provide more information about which parts of the object tree utf8json is struggling with.

Comment: It was throwing this exception: https://github.com/neuecc/Utf8Json/issues/91 seems to be a too simple management of dictionary keys.